# How do I know if it's safe to read from unaligned memory addresses on my machine?

Tags: c, linux, amazon-ec2, memory-alignment

I am aware that according to the C standard one's not allowed to perform an unaligned memory read, since it may result in a `SIGBUS`.

Nevertheless, I've seen some machines where this is not an issue.

How do I know if it's safe to read from unaligned memory on my machine? More specifically, I am using Amazon Linux.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              7981.41
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Comment: If you are not caught stealing a car, is stealing a car allowed?

Comment: I think, this sums it up quite well: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/unaligned-memory-access.txt

Comment: It is never safe, just trust the standard (can you quote or provide a link to the statement you're referring to ? )

Comment: This is not even a question of which machines support it - Linux has for some time patched it up on some platforms - so it's a question of  CPU, operating system and operating system configuration.

Comment: @marko, is there any way to know if my CPU, OS and OS config allow altogether unaligned reads? That's the question.

Comment: Write a program that attempts them and see whether it crashes?  This might be a viable proposition for feature detection in a build script. You can probably also do a probe at runtime if you catch the right signals.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that in most cases, misaligned access is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (if you claim to code portable and standard conformant C or C++ code).

**Undefined behavior is always [very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108)**, and it has the unpleasant property that sometimes it might seem to work (so having some program apparently work does not tell anything; it could break next time).

And in practice, on current machines accepting unaligned accesses (perhaps many x86_64 processors), such accesses are *very slow* because they make the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) unhappy (by needing two memory reads at the hardware level). See also [this](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

So simply **avoid unaligned access** (and other forms of UB, including [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)). Try to code for the standard, and follow common practice and wisdom. Enable all warnings in your compiler, and try to not get even a single one. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) again for more recommendations.

Comment: It's not *very slow* on modern x86 [since Sandy Bridge](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=627&v=t) https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128763/995714

Answer (score 3):

Will it "work" in the environment you have described?  "Yes", *(with a performance penalty.)*

Is it safe?  If you cross a busy street blindfolded and make it safely to the other side, was that "safe"?